# set a background css sprites image width

Tags: css, css-sprites

Is there a way to set a background css sprites image width?

```
<a href="#">shop</a>

a{
   background-image: url(http://placehold.it/60x60/ff0000/000&amp;text=100)!important;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;    
    background-position: -5px -5px;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jb1prcro/

right now the above `a` tag is 60px width, 30px for the word 'shop', 30px padding left for the cart icon,
because I am using css sprites for the background icons, right now it is showing 60px of that background image instead of just the 30px I want to show.

I also tried background-size: 30px 30px for this A tag, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo-element `before`:

```
a{
    display: inline-block;    
    background-position: -5px -5px;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    height:30px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
a:before {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/60x60/ff0000/000&amp;text=100)!important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  display:inline-block;
  content:'';
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/jb1prcro/2/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but here's a practical example:

https://jsfiddle.net/ozL0yzuy/

```
a {
   background-image: url(http://placehold.it/60x60/ff0000/000&amp;text=100)!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 40px;
    background-position: -10px -20px;  
}
```

You have to set a width (and actually also a height, which I didn't do in the example) for the element itself (in this case the `a` tag, which can only be done if its a block or inline-block element). Then you can adjust the background position accordingly.